# Issue installing TSD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tsd

Hey guy's I'm getting the following error code and didn't know if anyone had some solutions.  I'm not sure if it has something to do with my proxy and if so where to find the config file to correct the error.  Not sure why I'm getting the unexpected token error.

```
$ tsd init
[ERR!] cwd  : my\path\workspace\angular2
[ERR!] os   : Windows_NT 6.1.7601
[ERR!] argv : "my\path\nodejs\\node.exe" "my\path\\npm\\node_modules\\tsd\\build\\cli.js" "init"
[ERR!] node : v0.12.7
[ERR!] tsd  : 0.6.4
[ERR!] Error: Unexpected token {
[ERR!] CODE : undefined
[ERR!] Unexpected token {
[ERR!] If you need help, you may report this error at:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues

[ERR!] tsd.json could not be retrieved

[ERR!] .tsdrc could not be retrieved

[ERR!] Please include the following file with any support request:
my\path\\workspace\angular2\tsd-debug.log
```

I tried creating my own tsd.json config file but even with proxy setup etc it still failed.